# How to write video with OpenCV 3.0

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I want to write a video file with OpenCV 3.0, but I can't find `VideoWriter` class in the OpenCV Jar file. OpenCV 2.4.10 has a wrapper for Java calls, JavaCV 0.10, which had a `CvVideoWriter` Class. However, this class is not present in OpenCV 3.0.

What has happened to this class in OpenCV 3.0? Where may I find it? If it has been removed, how would I go about writing a video without it?

Comment: oh, that was fixed a few days ago. try again building opencv from github src. don't use obsolete javacv.

Comment: I downloaded the OpenCV for windows and extracted and there is jar file in the extracted folder, I am using that jar file in Eclipse, but you say build OpenCV from github, how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: alternatively, just wait a few days, until the buildbot catches up, and try to download again.

Comment: OpenCV already updated to version 3.0, but still I couldn't find VideoWriter class to write whit OpenCV 3.0.

Comment: videoio.VideoWriter()

Comment: Sorry there is no such method in Videoio class, There are only int constant.

Comment: again, update your (github) src code, and rebuild

Comment: How to do this with gethub, I am using the jar file which is auto generated while extracting the OpenCV package, it must be in this jar file.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d9/d52/tutorial_java_dev_intro.html

Comment: There i found this "Windows users can find the prebuilt files needed for Java development in the opencv/build/java/ folder inside the package. For other OSes it's required to build OpenCV from sources." it means that windows user can directly use the Java prebuilt jar file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79949/discussion-between-bahramdun-adil-and-berak).

Comment: So, what was the solution?

Comment: I did not find any solution till yet. If I find then I will share here.

Answer (score 0):

Now the problem has solved, the OpenCV version 3.0 doesn't have the function to write video in Java, but when OpenCV was updated to 3.1, then now it works well.